# Putting a '+' at center of a button

Tags: android, xml, button

This is the code for a button. I want to put the plus in the center (both vertical and horizontal). However, this is not working.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/zoomNineteen"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/zoomTwenty"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle= "bold"
        android:text="+" />
```

Comment: Could you make a screenshot?

Comment: It is not working for me with default button. I get the + slightly lower than center vertically. But with smaller text size it is center!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the attribute `android:gravity="center"` will center the text.

The problem you may be having is that most `Button` backgrounds in Android include a certain amount of padding as part of the image - this means it won't *look* centered.

In order for it to *look* centered you're going to need to also include:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"
```

pointing to either a custom image or more usefully a selector containing multiple images which don't include extra padding / margins.

Comment: I was wrong! not working even though I put the background to other shape without any padding